# Primefaces messages in a dialog is not displayed

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces, and have a login dialog:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="dlgLogin" header="Login" modal="true">
        <p:outputPanel>
            <h:form>
                <p:messages for="msgLogin" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" showSummary="true" showDetail="false" severity="error"/>
                <p:panel>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <p:outputLabel value="User Name"/>
                        <p:inputText id="userName" value="#{loginBean.userName}"
                                     required="true" requiredMessage="User Name is required"/>

                        <p:outputLabel value="Password"/>
                        <p:password id="password" value="#{loginBean.password}"
                                    required="true" requiredMessage="Password is required"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>
                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-n" value="Cancel" onclick="PF('dlgLogin').hide()"/>
                <p:commandButton type="submit" value="Login" 
                                 ajax="false" validateClient="true"
                                 oncomplete="handleClose(xhr, status, args);"
                                 action="#{loginBean.login}"/>
            </h:form>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:dialog>
```

Submitting the login is on purpose non ajax, so the entire page will be refreshed.

The server code is:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("msgLogin", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Wrong User Name or Password.", "Wrong User Name or Password."));
```

In case that the login fails in the server, I would like to display a message, and leave the dialog open. but it doesn't work.

How can that be done?

Thanks.

Comment: is `ajax="false"` really necessary for you? there are other ways to refresh the page in case of successful login, and it works pretty well as an ajax request. :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't close the dialog in JSF but in Java:

```
if (successfulLogin) {
    RequestContext.execute("PF('dlgLogin').hide()");
} else {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("msgLogin", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Wrong User Name or Password.", "Wrong User Name or Password."));
}
```

Comment: I have 2 problems: * The message is not displayed in the dialog. * I don't close the dialog, but the entire page is refreshed, as it is not ajax.

Comment: "In case that the login fails in the server, I would like to display a message, and leave the dialog open. but it doesn't work." - so not closing the dialog on default is the first step towards a solution, ain't it?

Comment: try to add this **update="@form"** to your **Login** button , or if its not working try to make the message tag outside of the your form

Comment: maybe my question wasn't clear: I have 2 cases: case 1 - if the login succeeds --> the entire page should update. (update="@all" has problems updating the dialogs, therefore I use ajax="false"). case 2 - if the login fails --> the page shouldn't submit, the dialog should remain open, and an error message should be displayed.

Comment: ok, I solved the problem. I removed the ajax="false" and in case that the login succeeds, the managed bean code reloads the page.